# MBP shutting down during sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, battery, sleep-wake, shutdown

I usually put my 2018 MBP into sleep by closing the lid (without any program open) and next time I only need to open the lid and unlock with fingerprint. However, it recently got an annoying behavior by occasionally shutting down during sleep, forcing me to login with password later.

Here is an excerpt from `pmset -g log` command:

```
Time stamp                Domain                Message                                                                     Duration    Delay     
==========                ======                =======                                                                     ========    =====     
UUID: 34379762-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
2019-06-11 03:19:05 +0700 Notification          Display is turned off                                                                 
2019-06-11 03:19:05 +0700 Assertions            PID 96(hidd) Summary UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle.4294969463.3" 00:00:03  id:0x0x900008230 [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2019-06-11 03:19:05 +0700 Assertions            PID 74(apsd) Summary ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-recreatecourierstate-push.apple.com" 00:00:02  id:0x0xb00008235 [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2019-06-11 03:19:05 +0700 Assertions            PID 74(apsd) Summary ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-recreatecourierstate-sandbox.push.apple.com" 00:00:02  id:0x0xb00008234 [System: DeclUser kDisp]          
2019-06-11 03:19:05 +0700 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: -None-          
2019-06-11 03:19:05 +0700 Assertions            PID 54(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.darkwakelinger" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008239 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2019-06-11 03:19:13 +0700 Assertions            PID 74(apsd) Released ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-recreatecourierstate-sandbox.push.apple.com" 00:00:10  id:0x0xb00008234 [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2019-06-11 03:19:13 +0700 Assertions            PID 74(apsd) Released ApplePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-recreatecourierstate-push.apple.com" 00:00:10  id:0x0xb00008235 [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2019-06-11 03:19:20 +0700 Assertions            PID 54(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.darkwakelinger" 00:00:15  id:0x0xd00008239 [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2019-06-11 03:19:20 +0700 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser kDisp] Using Batt(Charge: 28)          
2019-06-11 03:19:20 +0700 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=inactive Using Batt (Charge:28%)           
2019-06-11 03:19:23 +0700 Wake Requests         [*proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=43257]           
2019-06-11 03:19:23 +0700 PM Client Acks        Delays to Sleep notifications: [com.apple.apsd is slow(2693 ms)]           
2019-06-11 15:27:22 +0700 HibernateStats        hibmode=0 standbydelay=0                                                              0             
Sleep/Wakes since boot at 2019-06-11 01:52:34 +0700 :0   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:1

Time stamp                Domain                Message                                                                     Duration    Delay     
==========                ======                =======                                                                     ========    =====     
UUID: Unknown UUID
2019-06-11 15:27:22 +0700 Failure               Sleep Failure [code:0xFFFFFFFF0000001F]:                                              
Sleep/Wakes since boot at 2019-06-11 01:52:34 +0700 :0   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:1

Time stamp                Domain                Message                                                                     Duration    Delay     
==========                ======                =======                                                                     ========    =====     
UUID: (null)
2019-06-11 15:27:22 +0700 Start                 powerd process is started                                                             
2019-06-11 15:27:22 +0700 Assertions            Summary- [System: No Assertions] Using Batt          
2019-06-11 15:27:23 +0700 Assertions            Summary- [System: BGTask] Using AC(Charge: 23)          
2019-06-11 15:27:29 +0700 Assertions            PID 54(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "Assertion to change proximity monitoring state" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008007 [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2019-06-11 15:27:31 +0700 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler          
2019-06-11 15:27:42 +0700 Assertions            PID 96(hidd) Created UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle.4294968779.11" 00:00:00  id:0x0x9000080fc [System: PrevIdle DeclUser BGTask SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]
```

So, at 3:19 AM the laptop was put to sleep: `Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=inactive Using Batt`

However 3 seconds later there was a wake request from `[*proc=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff inDelta=43257]`. Also `HibernateStats  hibmode=0 standbydelay=0`.

I really don't know that means. Next time I open the lid at 15:27, this was put in log:

```
UUID: Unknown UUID
2019-06-11 15:27:22 +0700 Failure               Sleep Failure [code:0xFFFFFFFF0000001F]:
```

I already disabled *Power Nap* and *Wake for Wifi*, tried resetting NVRAM and SMC. Problem still occasionally happen.

Here is `pmset -g` settings:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 womp                 0
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 proximitywake        1
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 sleep                1
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 tcpkeepalive         1
 highstandbythreshold 50
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

The machine is running latest Mojave 10.14.5.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar problem. I'll try now if these will help:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25
sudo pmset -a standby 0
sudo pmset -a autopoweroff 0
```

I try to remember to post the results.